# How to get started with C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New to C++, help me get started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504238/new-to-c-help-me-get-started)

I'm trying to start learning c++, because I'd like to write a simple graphical game (like Missile Command for example).  I have had absolutely no luck finding a development environment that I can work with.  I tried Qt, Visual C++ Studio Express, and Code::Blocks with no success, can't even get to the Hello World level with any of them.  Qt was just way too complicated. Visual C++ is giving me "Cannot find or open the PDB file" and Code::Blocks says "couldn't create the project directory" even when I run them as administrator.

I know how to code, a little: I've done a lot of scripting work with AutoIt using the SciTE environment, and written a bunch of VBA code.  I just want to get started learning C++ so I can start doing some real graphics gaming stuff.  But it seems like it's impossible to get set up for even the most basic programming.  What am I doing wrong?

Sorry if this doesn't belong on Stackoverflow, if I should take it elsewhere please tell me where.

Comment: Your question is valid. Just it's a duplicate. Refer to the link posted by @Billy

Answer (score 0):

If you're really serious about learning C++ I would recommend C++ Primer Plus by Stephen Prata ([link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672326973)) It is by far the best introduction to standard C++ I've seen but note that it will only go over STANDARD C++. No graphics or game programming.